# my html page says an object i used earlier in my page does not exist

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

im trying to put in the username as a parameter in my link. doing this through jquery the only problem is i get this error,note the object call works for some reason on the span tag. I've been looking at tutorials but to no avail when trying to get the span tags value via $(#emailTarget).attr("id"); and putting said id onto the span tag it gives me the value of undefined rather than the username.

error stack

```
org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleText(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:80)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleText(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:208)
    at org.attoparser.AbstractChainedMarkupHandler.handleText(AbstractChainedMarkupHandler.java:203)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:557)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "principal.username" (template: "index" - line 49, col 25)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.process(TemplateManager.java:519)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.LazyProcessingCharSequence.writeUnresolved(LazyProcessingCharSequence.java:85)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.AbstractLazyCharSequence.write(AbstractLazyCharSequence.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.writeContent(AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.java:224)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Text.write(Text.java:78)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OutputTemplateHandler.handleText(OutputTemplateHandler.java:71)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'username' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
```

my home page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Registration and Login App</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
              crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Registration and
                        Login Module</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>Registration and Login with Spring Boot, Spring Security,
                Thymeleaf, Hibernate and MySQL</h1>
            Welcome <span sec:authentication="principal.username"> User</span>
        </div>
        <a th:href="login" id="changeMe" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script  type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
            let email=[[${principal.username}]];
            $('#changeMe').prop("href", "/delete?email="+email)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my repository url: https://github.com/jonathanIckovich/realtyKing.git

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a parameter in your link, use this: `<a th:href="@{/delete(email=${#authentication.principal.username})}">...</a>`. This will result in a uri like this: `/delete?email=test@example.com`.
If you want to substitute a path variable - `@{/delete/{email}(email=${#authentication.principal.username})}`.

However the problem you're facing seems more like an internal problem that is connected to `principal` being `null` (hence the error message) - this might happen because you're logged off. You should probably check for there being a principle (e.g. `#authentication.isAuthenticated()`) around the link that you're trying to build.